# Perform javascript code based on user input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing my own game using javascript and jQuery.
Right now I have a way for a user to type into a field and upon pressing enter it puts that text into a "textbox" (which is really just a div).

My function for this is as follows:

```
function input_field() {
var inputField = $('#dialog-input');
var messageField = $('#dialog-text');

inputField.keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        window.userInput = inputField.val();
        // Check if the input area is not empty (prevents adding white lines)
        if(userInput !== '') {
            messageField.append('You: ' + window.userInput + '<br>');
            inputField.val('');
            messageField.scrollTop(999999999);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
}
```

I also have a function for showing messages to the user that works as follows:

```
function cAlert(mssg) {
    var message = mssg;
    var messageField = $('#dialog-text');

    messageField.append(message + '<br>');
    messageField.scrollTop(999999999);
}
```

The problem here is that I want to turn this into a question+answer system, where the system asks a question (mostly in the shape of "You enter a room, what do you do?") and the user provides an answer (Look around).

I know I can do this using `prompt` and then checking the result with a `switch case`, but this will make my code look very ugly and not reusable.

**My question is:** how can I make the system wait for user input and then perform an action based on the given information?

Comment: @chandu I have multiple files. A fiddle is not an option.

Comment: Do you need something like [this](http://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/eHpbI)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to register an `onChange` listener in your input field :

```
$('#dialog-input').onChange(function() {
    // Handle user's input
});
```

This way, when the user presses `Enter` or leaves the field, your system will be notified.

Comment: My server? and what would I do in the onchange function?

Comment: Sorry, I mean system. In your listener, you can read the user's answer, and do something about that : reply, do an action, etc. The point here is that the onChange listener will be more efficient then the keyUp one, because the latter will fire an event for each character, which is not what you want.

Comment: But this wouldn't change how the code actually works with the output. I need the system to ask a question and wait for an answer. Right now I'm able to ask a question and give an answer, I just need the waiting part.

Comment: This actually **is** the waiting part... In javascript you have only 1 thread, so you cannot have a blocking thread. Thus, listeners are what you actually need as they do the same... in a non blocking way (which means your user will be able to perform actions while the server "waits")